# Which one is correct: a strong motivation or strong motivation?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, articles, indefinite-article

Can you tell me which one is grammatical and why ?

> When you start learning a new language, you need **a strong motivation**.

Or

> When you start learning a new language, you need **strong motivation.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are idiomatic, but they mean different things, because they use two separate definitions of "motivation."

If you say:

> When you start learning a new language, you need strong motivation

you are saying that you need a lot of willpower; the implication is that this willpower, or motivation, comes from within you.

If you say:

> When you start learning a new language, you need a strong motivation

you are saying that you need some specific incentive to learn; the implication is that this incentive, or motivation, is external.

For example:

> When you start learning a new language, you need strong motivation. If you slack off for even one day, you will forget everything.

As opposed to:

> When you start learning a new language, you need a strong motivation. My online boyfriend is a Nigerian prince, which really motivates me to study my Yoruba.